# How to make iFrame behave exactly as if one were accessing the source site directly?

Tags: html, redirect, iframe

I am working on a site for a Client and they want to display the following URL in an iFrame:

https://www.vigrxplus.com/ct/3134

If you access that site directly, it will show the Promo code on the source website.

However, if you access that site via an iFrame, it will **not** show the Promo code on the source website:

https://jsfiddle.net/qc3zvo0b/

```
<iframe width="100%" height="1000" src="https://www.vigrxplus.com/ct/3134"></iframe>
```

(Make sure to test the iFrame **without** prior Cookies from having previously visited the source website directly.)

Attempting to enable all sandbox features for iFrame did not fix this.

The source site also seems to do some kind of redirect.

So how can this be fixed such that the iFrame behaves just like visiting the site directly?